# Concurrency with a producer/consumer (sort of) and STL

Tags: c++, stl, concurrency

I have the following situation: I have two threads

- *thread1*, which is a worker thread that executes an algorithm until its input list size is > 0
- *thread2*, which is asynchronous (user driven) and can add elements to the input list to be processed

Now, *thread1* loop does something similar to the following

```
list input_list
list buffer_list

if (input_list.size() == 0)
  sleep

while (input_list.size() > 0) {
  for (item in input_list) {
    process(item);
    possibly add items to buffer_list
  }
  input_list = buffer_list (or copy it)
  buffer_list = new list (or empty it)
  sleep X ms (100 < X < 500, still have to decide)
}
```

Now *thread2* will just add elements to buffer_list (which will be the next pass of the algorithm) and possibly manage to awake *thread1* if it was stopped.

I'm trying to understand which multithread issues can occur in this situation, assuming that I'm programming it into C++ with aid of STL (no assumption on thread-safety of the implementation), and I have of course access to standard library (like mutex).

I would like to avoid any possible delay with *thread2*, since it's bound to user interface and it would create delays. I was thinking about using 3 lists to avoid synchronization issues but I'm not real sure so far. I'm still unsure either if there is a safer container within STL according to this specific situation.. I don't want to just place a mutex outside everything and lose so much performance.

Any advice would be very appreciated, thanks!

### EDIT:

This is what I managed so far, wondering if it's thread safe and enough efficient:

```
std::set<Item> *extBuffer, *innBuffer, *actBuffer;

void thread1Function()
{
  actBuffer->clear();
  sem_wait(&mutex);
  if (!extBuffer->empty())
    std::swap(actBuffer, extBuffer);
  sem_post(&mutex);
  if (!innBuffer->empty())
  {
    if (actBuffer->empty())
      std::swap(innBuffer, actBuffer);
    else if (!innBuffer->empty())
      actBuffer->insert(innBuffer->begin(), innBuffer->end());
  }

  if (!actBuffer->empty())
  {
    set<Item>::iterator it;
    for (it = actBuffer.begin; it != actBuffer.end(); ++it)
      // process
      // possibly innBuffer->insert(...)
  }
}

void thread2Add(Item item)
{
  sem_wait(&mutex);
  extBuffer->insert(item);
  sem_post(&mutex);

}
```

Probably I should open another question

Comment: what "standard library" do you have? C++11, boost.thread, pthreads?

Comment: I'm developing on iOS actually so I guess just pthreads of the one you mentioned

Comment: for a nice example: see http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/implementing-a-thread-safe-queue-using-condition-variables.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are worried about thread2 being blocked for a long time because thread1 is holding on to the lock, then make sure that thread1 guarentees to only take the lock for a really short time.

This can be easily accomplished if you have two instances of buffer list. So your attempt is already in the right direction.

Each buffer is pointed to with a pointer. One pointer you use to insert items into the list (thread2) and the other pointer is used to process the items in the other list (thread1). The insert operation of thread2 *must* be surrounded by a lock.

If thread1 is done processing all the items it only has to swap the pointers (e.g. with std::swap) this is a very quick operation which *must* be surrounded by a lock. Only the swap operation though. The actual processing of the items is lock-free.

This solution has the following advantages:

1. The lock in thread1 is always very short, so the amount of time that it may block thread2 is minimal
2. No constant dynamic allocation of buffers, which is faster and less likely to cause memory leak bugs.

Comment: This is indeed what I'm trying to achieve, the problem is that _thread1_ can add elements to the `buffer_list` while working, that's why I was thinking about having 2 buffer lists so that when _thread1_ is going to swap it will take the lock to `buffer_list2`, add its elements to `buffer_list` and then effectively swap them.

Answer (score 1):

You just need a mutex around inserting, removing, or when accessing the size of the container. You could develop a class to encapsulate the container and that would have the mutex. This would keep things simple and the class would handle the functionally of using he mutex.  If you limit the items accessing (what is exposed for functions/interfaces) and make the functions small (just calling the container classes function enacapsulated in the mutex), they will return relatively quickly. You should need only on list for this in that case.

Depending on the system, if you have semaphore available, you may want to check and see if they are more efficent and use them instead of the mutex.  Same concept applies, just in a different manner.

You may want to check in the concept of guards in case one of the threads dies, you would not get a deadlock condition.